# Cannot convert function to delegate

Tags: function, delegates, d

I have this function

```
 private ulong Html(ubyte[] data)
  {
    return data.length;
  }
```

that I want to convert to delegate by using [`toDelegate()`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_functional.html#toDelegate) function. I have tried it:

```
client.onReceive = toDelegate(&Html);
```

But I'm getting an error message:

```
lixo.d(722): Error: not a property client.onReceive
/home/$/D/libs/arsd/dom.d(743): Warning: statement is not reachable
/usr/include/d/dmd/phobos/std/range.d(595): Error: static assert  "Cannot put a dchar[] into a Appender!(char[])"
/usr/include/d/dmd/phobos/std/format.d(1758):        instantiated from here: put!(Appender!(char[]),dchar[])
/usr/include/d/dmd/phobos/std/format.d(1514):        instantiated from here: formatRange!(Appender!(char[]),dchar[],char)
/usr/include/d/dmd/phobos/std/conv.d(101):        instantiated from here: formatValue!(Appender!(char[]),dchar[],char)
/usr/include/d/dmd/phobos/std/conv.d(757):        ... (1 instantiations, -v to show) ...
/usr/include/d/dmd/phobos/std/conv.d(244):        instantiated from here: toImpl!(char[],dchar[])
/home/$/libs/arsd/dom.d(2115):        instantiated from here: to!(dchar[])
```

How to fix this?

Comment: The error is not about converting the function to delegate - it's about assigning it to `client.onReceive`. How is `onReceive` defined?

Comment: `client` is an instance of `HTTP` struct. In fact, if I do: `client.onReceive = (ubyte[] data) { return data.length; }` it works fine. dmd bug maybe?

Comment: length is of type size_t . Maybe you are getting some error/warning because of that?

Comment: It would be useful to post your compiler version and a more complete code listing. I can't recreate this error locally on dmd 2.060.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the /home/$/D/libs/arsd/dom.d library has a struct or class called '*Html*'. Try renaming your '*Html*' function to something else and see if it helps.

If it still doesn't work you probably have to show us more code as your example seems to work fine for me:
http://dpaste.dzfl.pl/fd729f3d

(I've seen similar errors before. For some reason the "not a property" error occurs a lot since dmd 2.060 even if the real error is not related.)